# Aligning my legends

Tags: html

I just want to know how to align this or make a column of this? I just want in the first row must be 4 colors and the rest will follow.

[click to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGXvL.png)

My code.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 text-center"></div>
      <div id="calendar" class="col-centered">
            <h3>Legends</h3>
            <div class="box-pink">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Kiamba
            </div><br/>
            <div class="box-ygreen">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Alabel
            </div><br/>
            <div class="box-sblue">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Maitum
            </div><br/>
            <div class="box-dgreen">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Malungon
            </div><br/>
            <div class="box-orange">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Glan
            </div><br/>
            <div class="box-rblue">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;South&nbsp;Cotabato
            </div><br/>
            <div class="box-yellow">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Gensan
            </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: post your css too

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't really get your question but is this what you need? Several rows with 4 columns in each of them? Take a look at the fiddle and see if it's what you need. You just need to change the position of the text wherever you seem fit.

[Possible Solution](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26035/)

```
    <div class ="container">
   <div class = "row">
    <h2>Legends</h2>
    <div class ="col-md-3 col-xs-3 col-lg-3">
    <img src ="http://tryingtobegood.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/straight-line-example-150x150@2x.png" id="test-img">
    <p >Kiamba</p>
    </div>
    <div class ="col-md-3 col-xs-3 col-lg-3">
    <img src ="http://tryingtobegood.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/straight-line-example-150x150@2x.png" id="test-img">
    <p>Alabel</p>
    </div>
    <div class ="col-md-3 col-xs-3 col-lg-3">
    <img src ="http://tryingtobegood.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/straight-line-example-150x150@2x.png" id="test-img">
    <p>Maitum</p>
    </div>
    <div class ="col-md-3 col-xs-3 col-lg-3">
    <img src ="http://tryingtobegood.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/straight-line-example-150x150@2x.png" id="test-img">
    <p>Lungon</p>
    </div>
    <div class ="col-md-3 col-xs-3 col-lg-3">
    <img src ="http://tryingtobegood.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/straight-line-example-150x150@2x.png" id="test-img">
    <p>Glan</p>
    </div>
    <div class ="col-md-3 col-xs-3 col-lg-3">
    <img src ="http://tryingtobegood.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/straight-line-example-150x150@2x.png" id="test-img">
    <p>South Catabato</p>
    </div>
    <div class ="col-md-3 col-xs-3 col-lg-3">
    <img src ="http://tryingtobegood.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/straight-line-example-150x150@2x.png" id="test-img">
    <p>Gensan</p>
    </div>
    <div class ="col-md-3 col-xs-3 col-lg-3">
    <img src ="http://tryingtobegood.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/straight-line-example-150x150@2x.png" id="test-img">
    <p>Legend8</p>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```